# Change eclipse key combo e.g. ALT+SHIFT+Q

Tags: eclipse

I have a question regarding the eclipse key bindings:
Is there a way to change "all" the "key combos" at once, for example "ALT + SHIFT + Q" into lets say "CONTROL + Z"

Otherwise one has to change EVERY "alt+shift+q" + "key" combination into "CONTROL + Z" + "key"

Thanks for your time